# Spring Data Rest exposes all entities without authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-data-rest

I have a spring boot project, you need to be authenticated to acess the project, I use OAuth2, this is my configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/rest/api/**").authenticated();
}
```

I did `permitAll()` to permit access to html files and I protected my rest controllers (/rest/api/), I'm also using `Spring Data Rest`, which expose all entities without authentication, so any non-authenticated user can access this `localhost:8080/entityName`.

I cannot do something like this: `antMatchers("/**").authenticated()`, because the server will block access to the IHM's, so how to protect entities from being exposed without removing `Spring .Data Rest`

Comment: Post your full Spring Security config.

Comment: First matched rule wins. Swap permitAll()  to the end.

Comment: @AlanHay: no /rest/api is protected, my question is how to protect the exposed entities as well .

Comment: Why don;t you have your rest entities under /api  then. The docs are pretty clear on this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-base-uri

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem.